# How can I add commas to generated number from my database and parseFloat that number to remove decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I have a table that outputs values from my database. I need to be able to add comma separators to that value and remove all decimal places.

I'm using this function to add comma separators dynamically

```
const numberWithCommas = (number) => {
        var parts = number.toString().split(".");
        parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        return parts.join(".");
    }
```

And then changing the text that's outputted to the  with this function. At the end of the function, I'm trying to use parseFloat() and toFixed() to remove any decimal places, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
$(".whole_dollar").each(function() {
            let num = $(this).text();
            let commaNum = numberWithCommas(num);
            parseFloat($(this).text(commaNum)).toFixed(0)
        });
```

This is the output on my table with the current function setups. The decimals are not being removed from the value.
[image]

This is my HTML. Any advice on how to achieve this is greatly appreciated!

```
            <table class="table text-light text-end table-borderless bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr class='text-center bordered'>
                        <th></th>
                        <th class="bordered" scope="col">CHW
                            <span class='units'>[tonhr]</span>
                        </th>
                        <th class="bordered" scope="col">ELE
                            <span class='units'>[kWh]</span>
                        </th>
                        <th class="bordered" scope="col">STM
                            <span class='units'>[lb]</span>
                        </th>                       
                        <th class="bordered" scope="col">HHW
                            <span class='units'>[mmbtu]</span>
                        </th>                                    
                        <th class="bordered" scope="col">GAS
                            <span class='units'>[CCF]</span>
                        </th>                       
                        <th class="bordered" scope="col">WTR
                            <span class='units'>[kgal]</span>
                        </th>                      
                        <th class="bordered" scope="col">Peak CHW
                            <span class='units'>[ton]</span>
                        </th>                      
                        <th class="bordered" scope="col">Labor
                            <span class='units'>[Hours]</span>
                        </th>
                        <th class="bordered" scope="col">Total
                            <span class='units'>[$]</span>
                        </th>
                        <th class="bordered" scope="col">Miscellaneous
                            <span class='units'>[$]</span>
                        </th>
                        <th class="bordered" scope="col">Annual Cash Flow
                            <span class='units'>[$]</span>
                        </th>
                        <th class="bordered" scope="col">Payback
                            <span class='units'>[years]</span>
                        </th>
                        <th class="bordered" scope="col">NPV
                            <span class='units'>[$]</span>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="bordered" scope="row">UEM</th>
                        {{#with chw3}}
                        <td class="whole_dollar bordered">{{fb_plus_fr}}</td>
                        {{else}}
                        <td class="bordered"></td>
                        {{/with}}
                        {{#with ele3}}
                        <td class="whole_dollar bordered">{{fb_plus_fr}}</td>
                        {{else}}
                        <td class="bordered"></td>
                        {{/with}}
                        {{#with stm3}}
                        <td class="whole_dollar bordered">{{fb_plus_fr}}</td>
                        {{else}}
                        <td class="bordered"></td>
                        {{/with}}
                        {{#with hhw3}}
                        <td class='whole_dollar bordered'>{{fb_plus_fr}}</td>
                        {{else}}
                        <td class="bordered"></td>
                        {{/with}}
                        {{#with gas3}}
                        <td class="whole_dollar bordered">{{fb_plus_fr}}</td>
                        {{else}}
                        <td class="bordered"></td>
                        {{/with}}
                        {{#with water3}}
                        <td class="whole_dollar bordered">{{fb_plus_fr}}</td>
                        {{else}}
                        <td class="bordered"></td>
                        {{/with}}
                        <td></td>
                        {{#with labor3}}
                        <td class="whole_dollar bordered">{{fb_plus_fr}}</td>
                        {{else}}
                        <td class="bordered"></td>
                        {{/with}}
                        {{#with total1}}
                        <td class='whole_dollar bordered'>{{fb_fr_total}}</td>
                        {{else}}
                        <td class="bordered"></td>
                        {{/with}}
                        {{#with misc1}}
                        <td class='whole_dollar bordered'>{{misc_savings}}</td>
                        {{else}}
                        <td class="bordered"></td>
                        {{/with}}
                        {{#with ann1}}
                        <td class='whole_dollar bordered'>{{cash_flow}}</td>
                        {{else}}
                        <td class="bordered"></td>
                        {{/with}}
                        {{#with payback1}}
                        <td class='years bordered'>{{payback}}</td>
                        {{else}}
                        <td class="bordered"></td>
                        {{/with}}
                        {{#with npv1}}
                        <td class='whole_dollar bordered'>{{npv}}</td>
                        {{else}}
                        <td class="bordered"></td>
                        {{/with}}
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: You need to apply the result of the `parseFloat().toFixed()` call to something, presumably the `text()` of the `td` element. Also, if you want to remove the floating point numbers it would make more sense to use `parseInt()` instead of `parseFloat()`. For future reference it's better to provide the HTML output in questions like this, where the templating engine in use is irrelevant to the question being asked. That way we can create a working example from your code.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. Just needed to place parseFloat on the num variable like this: let num = parseFloat($(this).text()).toFixed(0);

And I'm not sure what you mean by HTML output. I provided a screenshot of what the html looks like and provided the html code. Should I have included something else?

Comment: Sorry, I understand what you mean now. I should've included a screenshot of the actual HTML output, with the values that are outputted, rather than the actual code. I'll remember that for next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Figured out my problem. I just needed to place the parseFloat on the num variable, rather than placing it at the bottom. Like this:

```
        $(".whole_dollar").each(function() {
            let num = parseFloat($(this).text()).toFixed(0);
            let commaNum = numberWithCommas(num);
            $(this).text(commaNum)
        });
```

This is what I had before, the code that didn't work.

```
$(".whole_dollar").each(function() {
            let num = $(this).text();
            let commaNum = numberWithCommas(num);
            parseFloat($(this).text(commaNum)).toFixed(0)
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript's built in [.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) to add commas.

Note: you may have to declare the locale if you're somewhere in the world that doesn't use comma separators ie `.toLocaleString('en-US')`. Also `.toFixed(0)` seems to break this, so you can use [Math.trunc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) in this situation to achieve the same result.

```
$('.whole_dollar').each(function() {
  this.value = Math.trun(parseFloat(this.value)).toLocaleString();
});
```